# Find data on HTML file via input search box data saved in Google sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to extract data on an online HTML based site from data saved in Google Drive. Below is link of the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N9xUkG435rjiNn80Oe63JzwGPQvodRNh/edit#gid=987223181

I want data with heading as follows:

**Name | Codes | Code1 | Brn name | Address | CONTACT    | CITY |   DISTRICT    | STATE**

Search can be done with any of the columns content or mix of them.

I am having an excel sheet saved on google spreadsheet can be accessed with above link.

I am creating a single page html file in which any one can find the data which is written in excel file via Input box in html page then click on search button.

Results with the data matched will be shown in table below input button.

Actually I want to create a search box with button in blogger page that can initiate a query which can retrieve record based on search criteria from my Google spreadsheet and display that record on page. But I don't know how to connect blogger to Google spreadsheet. I can embed it but that will display all the records instead of based on criteria. Any help would be great.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, do you mind explaining to me what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so far? See [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the less information i have added more info if it can help to find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to use the [Google Visualization Query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to [Ingest data from sheets](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets). You may have to parse JSONP response depending on your environment.